# angular TS loop through incoming data

Tags: angular, typescript, loops

I am trying to loop through an array of incoming data so that I can display the information on a map in leaflet!

here is my class:

```
export class OpenStreetMapComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() private add = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() private edit = new EventEmitter<number>();
  artworkList: Artwork[];
```

the data as it comes in is stored in the artworkList array

```
constructor(private artworkService: ArtworkService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.refresh();
  }

  refresh() {
    this.artworkService.retrieveAll().then(
      artworkList => this.artworkList = artworkList
    );
    for (let artwork of this.artworkList) {
      console.log(artwork.name);
  }
```

for some reason i keep getting this error is my console:

ERROR TypeError: "_a is undefined"

Comment: You retrieve the data through an async call as promise, but you iterate over the array syncronously. You should move your for loop into the `then` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop operates synchronously, whereas you fetch the data it iterates over asynchronously.
You will have to move the actual loop into the `then`-block so that you do not access a possibly `undefined` value.

```
constructor(private artworkService: ArtworkService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.refresh();
}

refresh() {
  this.artworkService.retrieveAll().then((artworkList) => {
    this.artworkList = artworkList;
    for (let artwork of this.artworkList) {
      console.log(artwork.name);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.retriveAll()` method is a promise, you must `await` this method before attempting to make use of `this.artworkList`or you can place the following into the `.then` part of the call.

```
for (let artwork of this.artworkList) {
  console.log(artwork.name);
}
```

Currently, the loop is being run asynchronously along with the call to your method that returns a `Promise`, which is attempting to loop through an empty `this.artworkList`, causing the issue.